# Enumerating a grouped variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe using Python with patient ID numbers, each record representing a different appointment.  At each appointment a feature(dx) was recorded as 0 or 1.  I would like to create a new feature that sums the dx feature, but only up to that point for that patient.

```
patient_ID   |   dx   |   
 29847            0
 29847            1
 29847            0
 29847            1
 29847            1
```

I can get the sum of the group with a simple groupby statement:

```
df.groupby(['patient_ID])['dx'].sum()
```

but what I would like is for enumerated values as a new feature only considering the present and previous records:

```
patient_ID   |   dx   |   dx_enum
 29847            0         0
 29847            1         1
 29847            0         1
 29847            1         2
 29847            1         3
```

I imagine this will take a combination of a for-loop and a groupby statement, but have so far been unsuccessful. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you looking for just `cumsum()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're after you can add the column by performing a groupby and then calling `transform` and passing the function `cumsum`:

```
In [44]:

df['dx_enum'] = df.groupby('patient_ID')['dx'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
df
Out[44]:
   patient_ID  dx  dx_enum
0       29847   0        0
1       29847   1        1
2       29847   0        1
3       29847   1        2
4       29847   1        3
```

[Transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform) returns a series aligned to the original df so you can add it as a column, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: How sure are we that the OP  isn't simply looking for `cumsum`?  [by which I mean `df.groupby("patient_id")["dx"].cumsum()`]

Comment: @DSM dunno but this did what the OP was expecting, worth asking for more info I agree

Comment: I think the OP wants the groupby first, see my edited comment.